# How to make a component visible/available only for few set of users in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scenario where i need to show a component only to the admins not for the regular users.

Say,

```
<Parent>
  <ChildOne />
  <ChildTwo />     // This component should be rendered for public users.
  <ChildThree />
</Parent>
```

**What i have already tried**

I passed isAdmin prop from the parent to the child to determine whether the component visible status.

```
 const ChildTwoComp =  props.isAdmin ? <ChildTwo /> : null
 render () {
   return (
     <Parent>
       <ChildOne />
       {ChildTwoComp}    
       <ChildThree />
     </Parent>
    )
  }
```

I don't think I am doing it right. Is there any other better solution or right way to do it.

I want something similar to PrivateRoute concept in Reactjs. Any help appreciated.

Comment: In this piece of code you are never using your ChildTwo constant, but your ChildTwo component. Try to return {ChildTwo} instead of <ChildTwo/>

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it, it was a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a role based component and use it as a wrapper.

**RoleBasedComponent.js**

```
const RoleBasedComponent = ({ children, supportedRoles, role }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {supportedRoles.indexOf(role) > -1 ? children : <h2>Access Denied</h2>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RoleBasedComponent;
```

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <RoleBasedComponent
      role={"admin"}
      supportedRoles={["admin", "support_admin", "user"]}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </RoleBasedComponent>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo https://codesandbox.io/s/ql9p2q0kxq

Comment: Thank you, this is much better.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

`{!isAdmin && <ChildTwo />}`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put your ternary inside the JSX :

```
render () {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <ChildOne />
      {this.props.isAdmin ? <ChildTwo /> : null}    
      <ChildThree />
    </Parent>
  )
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know about this one. But what if i want this same condition for multiple components in different page. Wouldn't be a redundant one?